# Steps to use the Directus CMS API

Tags: api, directus

I just installed Directus, but I have to create the HTML interface, and I can't extract the data via the API. How can I use the static API? That is, with some kind of static token (the front will do it with PHP).

I have the Directus suite (APP + API https://github.com/directus/directus) installed and the HTML will be hosted on the same server.

Answer (score 2):

Directus has built-in static tokens that can be assigned to any Directus User, and inherits that user's permissions. You can set this static token in `directus_users.token` (plaintext), and then use it to authenticate to the API. This is less secure than the other auth methods, but that depends on how you use it.

https://docs.directus.io/api/reference.html#tokens

The other option would be to set the data you need to "public". Obviously that only works if that data *is* public (READ)... but that is the case for many websites.

Comment: What is `directus_users.token` and where do I find it? Unfortunately, the link doesn't work anymore. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks RANGER, I have the following installation:

URL:
https://cms.domain.com/public/ (APP + API Directus)

I have reviewed the column of the table you comment, and there is indeed a token already established:
BGJFwQ1KlHnH91V2oIwMbOsG

```
$contents = file_get_contents('https://cms.domain.com/public/_/collections/categories?access_token=BGJFwQ1KlHnH91V2oIwMbOsG');
var_dump($contents);
```

But it does not work, I have read the documentation more than 10 times and I have been with the subject for days, I wanted to solve it myself, but I cannot find the error using file_get_contents () or curl in PHP to call the API.

The Directus ADMIN is in:
https://cms.domain.com/public/admin/#/

I have taken the token from the ADMIN user, and therefore I understand that you have all the permissions to use the API. In the example, I wanted to list the "categories" (collection), which have 3 records.

Solved: curl https://cms.domain.com/public/name-of-project/collections?access_token=BGJFwQ1KlHnH91V2oIwMb34343G

**Solved: I should use the **project name** instead of "**_**" (default project).**

I am sorry that it is such a basic mistake, but I have come across several people with this problem.